# How to delete a 'dead' remote project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have a remote project in Eclipse which was created through RSE's 'Create Remote Project' function. Now I changed hosting service and there's no option to connect to former host. When I try to delete this remote project Eclipse asks me for former host's login and password which if entered are not recognized anyway.

How can I delete the project?

*Note:* My workspace folder contains 'RemoteSystemsTempFiles' folder and there are no files related to this project there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally found it. I did the following:

- deleted relevant folder in `workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.projects/`
- relaunched Eclipse
- the project was still there but Eclipse let me 'legally' delete it with right-click

Comment: But after restart it will re-create it again. Any ideas on why it's created and how to stop it?

Comment: @yentsun works great totally a life saver!
Also, to delete a local connection under RSE view delete the folder from: eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.rse.core/profiles

Answer (score 3):

The answer is to brows to workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.rse.core\profiles\PRF.${hostname}

Then delete the directory with the name H.${profilename}

Answer (score 2):

You might check into the "workspace/.metadata/.plugins" directory to find the RSE plugin's data storage area. It will probably have an xml file or something with the reference to your project. Back it up and delete the reference. Hopefully this will remove it from your view.

Sorry I cannot be more specific, this is just a suggestion that I am not able to try explicitly.

Good luck, and like I said, back up the files you change... just in case.

Comment: in workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.rse.core/profiles I found and deleted relevant folder. The project did not disappear fromview but it now doesn't ask for login and pass when being deleted. But Eclipse still fails to delete it :(

Comment: You might try doing a search for the project name under the .plugins directory... maybe another plugin manages the project view for RSE. What a pain in the butt.

Answer (score 0):

With my Kepler setup, I found this subdir in workspace that had a folder for each domain.  I rm'd the outdated ones

```
<workspace path>/RemoteSystemsTempFiles/ABC.DOMAIN.COM
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that works for me - hide the project:

Go to "Project Explorer > Customize view", and uncheck "RSE internal projects".